# How to hijack .findAll by NamedNativeQuery?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I do have a query need to customize but i need to maintain the pagination and sorting function. Is there any possible to point when call .findAll to my NamedNativeQuery?

call findAll

```
Page<Customer> page = customerDao.findAll(specifications,
            new PageRequest(pageNo, limit, Utils.jasonToSort(sorts)));
```

my NamedNativeQuery (the query statement will come with union join)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
       name = "Customer.findAll", 
       query = "SELECT ID, Customer_Name, Customer_DESC FROM Customer WHERE Customer_Name = :Cust_Name") })
```

Actually my actual query is more complex with Union join, and parameter.
Is there a way to point .findAll to the NamedNativeQuery and pass in a parameter?

Thank You

Comment: Where is this `findAll`? Is this a Spring Data JPA repository?

Comment: yes.. is a JPA repository

Comment: Just redeclare `findAll` and supply a custom query as you would for any other repository method.

Comment: sorry i'm not so familiar with JPA. 1. if redeclare possible still can remain use the pagination and sort function ?